# Code challenge: Bash prompt path shortener

Tags: bash, path, prompt

I implemented a prompt path shortener for bash to be included in the PS1 environment variable, which shortens the working directory into something more compact but still descriptive. I'm curious what other ideas may exist.

Here's the challenge:

Create a bash function `_dir_chomp` which can be included into PS1 like this (line breaks inserted for readability):

```
PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] $(
  _dir_chomp "$(pwd)" 20
)\[\033[01;37m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[01;34m\] \$\[\033[00m\] '
```

with "20" being the parameter for the maximum length as soft limit. These are the examples:

1. `/usr/portage/media-plugins/banshee-community-extensions/files` becomes `/u/p/m/b/files`
2. `/home/user1/media/video/music/live-sets` becomes `~/m/v/m/live-sets` (note the ~ character as replacement for $HOME)
3. `/home/user2/media` does NOT change (20 char limit not exceeded)
4. `/home/user1/this-is-a-very-long-path-name-with-more-than-20-chars` becomes `~/this-is-a-very-long-path-name-with-more-than-20-chars` (last component stays unshortened: soft limit)
5. `/home/user1/src` becomes `~/src` ($HOME always shortened)
6. `/home/user1/.kde4/share/config/kresources` becomes `~/.k/s/c/kresources` (note the prefixing dot is preserved)

Current user is user1.

It's allowed to call external interpreters like `awk`, `perl`, `ruby`, `python` but not compiled C programs or similar. In other words: external source files are not allowed, code must be inline. Shortest version wins. The length of the bash function body (and called sub functions) counts, means:

```
_sub_helper() {
  # this counts
}
_dir_chomp() {
  # these characters count (between { and })
  _sub_helper "foobar" # _sub_helper body counts, too
}
```

Comment: I notice you have `parse_git_branch` - is that something you prefer to `__git_ps1`?

Comment: And really, as long as someone takes the time to go for it, I doubt anything could beat an unreadable-but-short perl solution.

Comment: @Jefromi: That's just a one liner: `git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ [git:\1]/'`. BTW: My solution to this is ruby, not perl. And pretty readable although a one-liner, too.

Comment: See this solution: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26860/6128 It's not exactly to requirements but easily modified.

Comment: Allowing awk, perl, ruby and python is not a good idea for this challenge: a prompt must not just be short in code, it should be light in external programs loaded (fork+exec) to stay fast.

Comment: @dolmen -- In principle, yes. But the prompt only gets evaluated once per user command, so you can afford several tens of milliseconds or so. On my laptop I can start up Perl from bash and run a trivial Perl script in under 4 milliseconds, and a small but non-trivial one in under 20 msec. So there's room to do this kind of thing if you're careful.

Answer (score 13):

Pure Bash:

```
_dir_chomp () {
    local IFS=/ c=1 n d
    local p=(${1/#$HOME/\~}) r=${p[*]}
    local s=${#r}
    while ((s>$2&&c<${#p[*]}-1))
    do
        d=${p[c]}
        n=1;[[ $d = .* ]]&&n=2
        ((s-=${#d}-n))
        p[c++]=${d:0:n}
    done
    echo "${p[*]}"
}
```

For purposes of testing, I'm assuming that the question means that the current user is "user1".

Note: Bash 4 has a variable `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` that shortens the `\w` escape in `PS1` by retaining the number of sub-directories according to its value and replacing the rest with `...`

```
/$ PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2
/$ echo $PS1
\w\$
/$ pwd
/
/$ cd /usr/share/doc/bash
.../doc/bash$
```

Comment: Well PROMPT_DIRTRIM is too terse for me so I created my own solution.

Answer (score 8):

This one is 20 or so characters shorter than my other answer:

```
_dir_chomp () {
    local p=${1/#$HOME/\~} b s
    s=${#p}
    while [[ $p != "${p//\/}" ]]&&(($s>$2))
    do
        p=${p#/}
        [[ $p =~ \.?. ]]
        b=$b/${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
        p=${p#*/}
        ((s=${#b}+${#p}))
    done
    echo ${b/\/~/\~}${b+/}$p
}
```

Comment: I like the pure bash approach.

Comment: Both my answers are pure Bash, by the way.

Comment: I mean in contrast to my ruby solution.

Comment: NB, make sure to quote `$PWD` when using this to set `PS1` — maybe obvious to others, but I had been suffering with `bash: ... division by 0` for months before working out. //i.e.// `PS1='$(_dir_chomp "$PWD" 20)'`

Answer (score 1):

This was my own solution when I had the idea for this challenge. The inspiration actually came from [Jolexa's Blog](http://blog.jolexa.net/2010/08/16/linux-my-bash-prompt/).

So here it is, the ruby implementation in readable form:

```
a = ARGV[1].gsub(%r{^#{ENV['HOME']}}, "~")
b, a = a, a.gsub(%r{/(\.?[^/.])[^/]+(/.*)}, '/\1\2') while
  (a.length > ARGV[2].to_i) && (b != a)
print a
```

And the actual one-line implementation within the bash function:

```
_dir_chomp() {
  ruby -e'a="'$1'".gsub(%r{^'$HOME'},"~");b,a=a,a.gsub(%r{/(\.?[^/.])[^/]+(/.*)},"/\\1\\2")while(a.length>'$2')&&(b!=a);print a'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with only bash internals, no use of sed

```
shortpath()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
{           
    dir=${1%/*} && last=${1##*/}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

    res=$(for i in ${dir//\// } ; do echo -n "${i:0:3}../" ; done)                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    echo "/$res$last"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

My previous solution, with bash and sed.
it cut each dir in 3 first caracters and add '..' like this:
/hom../obo../tmp../exa../bas../

```
shortpath()
{
        dir=$(dirname $1)
        last=$(basename $1)

        v=${dir//\// } # replace / by <space> in path
        t=$(printf "echo %s | sed -e 's/^\(...\).*$/\\\1../' ; " $v) 
            # prepare command line, cut names to 3 char and add '..'
        a=$(eval $t) 
            # a will contain list of 3 char words ended with '..' ans separated with ' '

        echo " "$a"/"$last | sed -e 's/ /\//g'
}
```

Comment: I would prefer `/home/obor/tmp/exa../bas../`, which is shorter.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I shorten my bash prompt w/ full path in titlebar (works since 3.0):

```
_PS1P=('' '..')
PROMPT_COMMAND='_PS1L=${#DIRSTACK[0]} _PS1D=${DIRSTACK[0]}'
PS1='\[\e]2;\h:\w\a\]\h ${_PS1P[$_PS1L>36]}${_PS1D:$_PS1L>36?-34:0} \$ '
```

This method requires very low CPU overhead.