# How to shorten path parts between // in bash

Tags: bash, sed, prompt

I want my bash prompt paths to be shortened:

```
~/workspace/project/my-project
# Should be
~/w/p/my-project
```

This could be achieved by just shortening parts of the path string between // to just the first character.

Is there a way to do this for example in sed?

edit:

Thought someone else looking into this might find what I ended useful so I'm editing it here.

.bashrc:

```
dir_chomp () {
    pwd | sed "s|^$HOME|~|" 2> /dev/null | sed 's:\(\.\?[^/]\)[^/]*/:\1/:g'
}

parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

export PS1="\[\033[32m\]\$(dir_chomp)\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

prompt examples (coloring doesn't show):

```
~/w/e/coolstuff (master) $
~/.c/A/Cache $
```

Comment: I feel like that's bound to be wrong since this `parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}` works fine in this prompt: `export PS1="\[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "`

Comment: @lurker: However, if you set `PS1=\$(parse_git_branch)`, then `PS1` *is* re-evaluated every time.

Comment: You should take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497885/code-challenge-bash-prompt-path-shortener) post.

Comment: @lurker It **is** being evaluated everytime, try it out.

Comment: @drewyupdrew Thanks for the link, unfortunately the bash functions don't seem to work and I don't want to install ruby to get this running.

Comment: @RusinaRange: Really, piping one sed into another is pointlessly inefficient; you can just separate the two commands with a semicolon or use two `-e` options as in your `parse_git_branch` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to unconditionally shorten all path components, you can do it quite easily with `sed`:

```
sed 's:\([^/]\)[^/]*/:\1/:g'
```

If you want to also insert `~` at the beginning of paths which start with `$HOME`, you can add that to the sed command (although this naive version assumes that `$HOME` does not include a colon).

```
sed 's:^'"$HOME"':~:/;s:\([^/]\)[^/]*/:\1/:g'
```

A better solution is to use bash substitution:

```
short_pwd() {
  local pwd=$(pwd)
  pwd=${pwd/#$HOME/\~}
  sed 's:\([^/]\)[^/]*/:\1/:g' <<<"$pwd"
}
```

With that bash function, you can then "call" it from your PS1 string:

```
$ PS1='$(short_pwd)\$ '
~/s/tmp$ PS1='\$ '
$
```

Comment: This works when you pipe it like this: `pwd | sed "s|^$HOME|~|" 2> /dev/null | sed 's/\([^/]\)[^/]*\//\1\//g'`. Could this be modified to shorten to one char AND preserve leading dots?

Comment: As in `~/.config/anapp/settings` -> `~/.c/a/settings`

Comment: @RusinaRange: Now you are changing the goal-posts :)

Comment: I am :P didn't realize that'd be a problem before I tried your solution and went to the config folder :D Anyway, gonna mark this as solved, would be nice to get that dot though.

Comment: Thanks a ton! One last question, is there any difference between your bash substitution and my piping?

Comment: @lurker Not concerned about that

Comment: @RusinaRange: The bash substitution is more robust. There is no difference between my two-command sed version and your pipe, other than that my version is a lot more efficient (only one sed process).

Answer (score 1):

Use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to set your prompt dynamically each time it is displayed.

```
shorten_path () {
    cwd=${PWD/workspace/w}
    cwd=${cwd/project/p}
    cwd=${cwd/$HOME/~}
    PS1="$cwd "'\$ '
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=shorten_path
```

This replaces the use of `\w` escape with custom code to shorten the current working directory. It has the unfortunate side effect of replacing `~` with the name of your home directory, though, which is why the third line is necessary to put it back, if desired.

Comment: Yes; I may have taken your question too specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to shorten to 3 caracters plus "..":

```
shortpath() 
{
    dir=${1%/*} && last=${1##*/}
    res=$(for i in ${dir//\// } ; do echo -n "${i:0:3}../" ; done)
    echo "/$res$last"
}
```

Version to short to one caracter:

```
shortpath() 
{
    dir=${1%/*} && last=${1##*/}
    res=$(for i in ${dir//\// } ; do echo -n "${i:0:1}/" ; done)
    echo "/$res$last"
}
```

And then:

```
export PS1="\$(shortpath \$(pwd)) $"
```